# Draw continuous trend line for separate calculated measures

Tags: tableau-api, calculated-field

Sheet 1: I've created 5 separate calculated measure fields to show 1+, 2+, 3+, 4+ and 5+ months based on the Number of Days data field. This is the undesired output for these fields

Sheet 2: Desired Output for Sheet 1

I want to create a trend line for the number of Distinct ID's falling in each month+ field. I've taken the output numbers and constructed Sheet 2 to show the Desired Output.
How do I make this happen for Sheet 1 based on the calculated fields and other measures only? Is there any other way of doing this? Thanks

[image: Undesired Output]

[image: Desired Output for Sheet 1]

Tableau 9.3 Workbook-

[Packaged Workbook Download](https://community.tableau.com/servlet/JiveServlet/download/542236-153026/Continuous%20Measure%20Divisions.twbx)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set it up like this and you will get your line.

[image]

You could also get something like this to have it more detailled:
[image]

The `[date]` field has this formula : `DATEADD('day', [Days], NOW())`
and use a table calculation for the count like this

[image]

If you don't want to have it based on `NOW()` you could just use a date parameter to set a dynamic anchor.